# How to make git maintain a git.properties file containing select information

Tags: git, maven

We have a need for using the git branch and commit hash in our maven build.

Is there a simple way to have git automatically maintain a "git.properties" file with the information we need, so that it always reflect the current state of git?

We would like this to be a platform-agnostic solution if at all possible

---

Edit 2022:  I did some work on capturing this information as Java source using annotation processing so no property file is needed.  Promising but not yet production quality.

Comment: What do you require within the git.properties file? The commit hash of a branch?

Comment: I need the name of the branch as reported by `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`and the current hash as reported by `git rev-parse HEAD` on as two lines "git.branch=xxxx" and "git.hash=yyyy".

Answer (score 3):

Note (2016, but actually created in Sept. 2011), there is a maven plugin dedicated to capture Git information in a property file.
It is the [**ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin**](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin) one.

```xml
  <dependency>
      <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Then:

```xml
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.1</version>
          <executions>
              <phase>initialize</phase>
              <execution>
                  <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>revision</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
              <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

In your case, since you "need this information so early in the Maven build process", I have added the `<phase>initialize</phase>` in order to trigger it as early as possible in the default jar maven lifecycle.

Then I used it during the execution of my plugin, in order to print a Git-related debug data which helps knowing the exact version of that plugin.

```java
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("git.properties");
  if (stream != null) {
      prop.load(stream);
      String dirty = prop.getProperty("git.dirty");
      if (dirty.equals("false")) {
          dirty = "";
      } else {
          dirty = "(dirty)";
      }
      ver = ver + prop.getProperty("git.build.version")+dirty;
      ver = ver + " - " + prop.getProperty("git.commit.id.describe");
      ver = ver + " - " + prop.getProperty("git.build.time");
  } else {
      throw new MojoFailureException("Unable to find MyProject git.properties");
  }
```

---

[Lubo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11152683/lubo) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584006/how-to-make-git-maintain-a-git-properties-file-containing-select-information/39205630?noredirect=1#comment135170249_39205630):

> To make `target/classes/git.properties` file updated manually:
>
> ```
> mvn pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:revision
> ```

Comment: `mvn pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:revision` to make target/classes/git.properties file updated manually.

Comment: @Lubo Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.